# Find largest element smaller than current with STL

Tags: c++11, stl

Is there a single one-liner to find the largest element smaller than some element x in a sorted container? I'm essentially interested in any code that will give me an iterator pointing to the largest element smaller than x.

I know how to code this up myself, but would hope that there is a library function for it...

EDIT: Maybe I should make myself clear here, that the version I have in mind that I would code myself is based on binary search and thus runs in O(log n) time. I need to compute this for lists with up to a few million elements.

Comment: `std::max_element(container.begin(), std::lower_bound(container.begin(), container.end(), x));`

Comment: Is this O(log n) complexity, which any binary search based approach would provide? (i.e. the version I would code up myself, since the container is sorted)

Comment: This would be faster though, even if not as elegant: `auto bound = std::lower_bound(container.begin(), container.end()); if (bound != container.begin()) --bound; else bound = container.end();}` Basically, find the position of an element that's `x` or greater, step down by one position (be careful of edge conditions). This just performs one binary search.

Comment: @JT1 for a sorted container, yes, the provided solutions are O(log(n))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your container is sorted, you can use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) on a range ending with the first element greater than your max, use `std::find_if` with a lambda, or `std::lower_bound` to get this range :

```
int main()
{
    std::set<int> s{ 3, 1, -14, 1, 5, 9 }; 
    std::set<int>::iterator result;

    int max_value = 6;
    result = std::max_element(std::begin(s), std::find_if(std::begin(s), std::end(s), [&](int i) { return i >= max_value; } ) );
    std::cout << "max element is: " << *result;
}
```

**Output :**

> max element is: 5

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e75cd14ca706181c)

Or with `std::lower_bound` :

```
int main()
{
    std::set<int> s{ 3, 1, -14, 1, 5, 9 }; 
    std::set<int>::iterator result;

    int max_value = 6;
    result = std::max_element(std::begin(s), std::lower_bound(std::begin(s), std::end(s), max_value)) ;
    std::cout << "max element is: " << *result;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0151cce9a00e5372)**

Comment: These snippets assume there's always an element smaller than max_value. Otherwise is returns the smallest element in the container:
`max_value = -20  // => result -14`

Answer (score 3):

You can just use

```
lower_bound(container.begin(), container.end(), currentElement);
```

Now if that is different than `container.begin()` then there is an element that is smaller than your current one, just substract one and you get it. If you are sure there is always such an element just do

```
lower_bound(container.begin(), container.end(), currentElement) - 1;
```

EDIT: Of course I assume that your iterator is bidirectional.

Answer (score 2):

Use `prev()` in combination with `lower_bound()`

- `mycontainer.lower_bound(int_val)` returns an iterator to the number that's equal to or greater than int_val
- `*prev(mycontainer.lower_bound(int_val))` returns the value just before int_val in the container

As a defensive check, first validate that it's not at the beginning of the container:

```
int result = -1, target = 15;
set<int> _container;
auto _iterator = _container.lower_bound(target);
if(_iterator != _container.begin())
   result = *std::prev(_iterator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your data in a set `s` of integers, you can find the largest element smaller than x as follows:

```
auto it = s.lower_bound( x ); // s.lower_bound has a complexity of O(logn)
if( it == s.begin() )
{
    std::cout << "No element found" << "\n";
}
else
{
    --it;
    std::cout << *it << "\n";
}
```

`lower_bound` essentially returns you an iterator `it` pointing to the smallest element which is `>= x`. Therefore, it's just previous pointer `--it` would point to the largest element which is `< x`. Complexity of this approach is `O(log n)`.